# SFTP user root directory

Tags: bash

I've assembled the following script that works fine. It will create a sftp user and when the user logs in they will be in `/var/base/test1`, of which they can't write in this directory, they need to then enter `/var/base/test1/test1` and then they can write.

However, it is a bit annoying and ideally I want the user to enter in to `/var/base/test1/test1` directory when they log in via ftp. Is there a way to facilitate this? If I change the ChrootDirectory (in sshd_config) to `/var/base/test1/test1`, then the ftp user can no longer log in.

```
mkdir -p /var/base/test1/test1
chown root:root /var/base/test1
chown root:root /var/base
chmod 755 /var/base/test1
adduser --disabled-password --gecos test1
echo “test1:apassword” | chpasswd
chown test1:test1 /var/base/test1/test1
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
systemctl restart sshd
```

sshd_config:

```
Match User test1
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /var/base/test1
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

This is not possible, but set home to `/test1` as a workaround.

#### Long answer

`openssh` requires that the `ChrootDirectory` and all path components leading to it are root owned and not writable by anyone else. This is a security measure to ensure the `ChrootDirectory` can't be maliciously manipulated and e.g. replaced by a symlink to somewhere completely else. If the `ChrootDirectory` or any of its parent directories are not owned by root or are group or world writable, `sshd` refuses login. If this happens, you see something like this in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Jun 10 07:54:01 ubuntu-bionic sshd[2251]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/base/test1"
Jun 10 07:54:01 ubuntu-bionic sshd[2173]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user test1
```

The error message should point you in the right direction.

This is also explicitly stated on the [sshd_config man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

> **ChrootDirectory**
>   Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after
>   authentication.  At session startup sshd(8) checks that all
>   components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are
>   not writable by any other user or group. After the chroot,
>   sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home
>   directory. *[...]*
>
> For safety, it is very important that the directory hierarchy be
>   prevented from modification by other processes on the system
>   (especially those outside the jail).  Misconfiguration can lead
>   to unsafe environments which sshd(8) cannot detect.

#### Workaround

You can, however, set the home directory of the user to `/test1` (`sudo usermod test1 -d /test1`), that way after the `chroot` is applied the directory is changed to `/var/base/test1/test1`. That way the user doesn't need to change to `test1` but starts his `sftp` session already in that directory.

```
$ sftp -P 2222 test1@localhost
test1@localhost's password: 
Connected to localhost.
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /test1
```

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thanks so much for your testing and explanation. I've tested and your workaround works.